# How to use clusters in UI5 map?

Tags: sapui5

I have a basic SAP UI5 map, a GeoMap in a MapContainer with Spots. I would like to use clustering, but I can't find out, how to do that, a long time ago.

Here you can see my basic geomap, with the spots from oData. I just need a prety basic solution of creating clusters.

```
<vk:MapContainer id="mcont" autoAdjustHeight="true" class="myMapContainer" settingsPressed=".changeMapLayer" showSelection="false" showSettings="false" showRectangularZoom="false" showHome="false">
            <vk:content>
                <vk:ContainerContent id="mcont_content" title="Geo Map" icon="sap-icon://geographic-bubble-chart">
                    <vk:content>
                        <vbm:GeoMap id="GeoMap" zoomlevel="9" centerPosition="16.293671;48.162477" busyIndicatorDelay="0">

                            <vbm:vos>
                                <vbm:Spots id="_IDGenSpots1" items="{ path: '/LagerkarteSet' }">
                                    <vbm:Spot
                                        id="_IDGenSpot1"
                                        type="{= ${TypLort} === 'L' ? 'Warning' : 'Success' }"
                                        position="{YCoord};{XCoord};0"
                                    />
                                </vbm:Spots>
                            </vbm:vos>
                        </vbm:GeoMap>
                    </vk:content>
                </vk:ContainerContent>
            </vk:content>
        </vk:MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the aggregation "clusters" like below:

```
<vk:MapContainer id="mcont" autoAdjustHeight="true" class="myMapContainer" settingsPressed=".changeMapLayer" showSelection="false" showSettings="false" showRectangularZoom="false" showHome="false">
        <vk:content>
            <vk:ContainerContent id="mcont_content" title="Geo Map" icon="sap-icon://geographic-bubble-chart">
                <vk:content>
                    <vbm:GeoMap id="GeoMap" zoomlevel="9" centerPosition="16.293671;48.162477" busyIndicatorDelay="0">

                        <vbm:vos>
                            <vbm:Spots id="_IDGenSpots1" items="{ path: '/LagerkarteSet' }">
                                <vbm:Spot
                                    id="_IDGenSpot1"
                                    type="{= ${TypLort} === 'L' ? 'Warning' : 'Success' }"
                                    position="{YCoord};{XCoord};0"
                                />
                            </vbm:Spots>
                        </vbm:vos>

               <vbm:clusters>
                  <vbm:ClusterDistance>
                     <vbm:Cluster type="Success" icon="shipping-status" />
                  </vbm:ClusterDistance>
              </vbm:clusters>


                    </vbm:GeoMap>
                </vk:content>
            </vk:ContainerContent>
        </vk:content>
    </vk:MapContainer>
```

It's possible to use different types of clustering (ClusterDistance, ClusterGrid or ClusterTree) and also set rules in order to only cluster a partial set of your spots.